# Jquery's get vs post for login/registration

Tags: jquery

I read few SO posts to find differences for these two methods. In all the pages, I see a word `Idempotent` for `GET`. My doubt is, in the registration page, there are only two options. One is registration successfull/existing email. So it will return the same result all the time.[`Did i misunderstand idempotent's meaning here?`] So could i use GET here?

Which one is appropriate? What is the advantage over another in this scenario?

Comment: if you're registerring, you'll be sending personal information things like passwords, so you should use `POST`, otherwise that info will be in the URL.

Comment: Yes. I know hackers are best. Even though this doubt  strikes in my mind. If i encrypt and send?

Comment: A general rule of thumb I use is that if I'm telling the server something (i.e. "a user is registering with this data," or "a user is logging in with this data") you use `POST`. If you're asking the server for something (i.e. "what is on this page?") you use `GET`. In both instances here, you should use `POST`.

Comment: "Idempotent" means that nothing will change on the server's side. `GET` requests are idempotent because they will never modify the data on the server. `POST` requests, on the other hand, will almost always modify the data on the server. When logging in/registering, you are modifying something on the server, so you should always use `POST` (plus it's a bit more secure for logging in than using a `GET` request)

Comment: Ohkay @RevanProdigalKnight I thought it means only the returning result. I din't know that it's about changing the server contents

Comment: @DLeh can u add ans?

Answer (score 0):

if you use GET request then Password will be presented in the URL and will be security risk, using POST then paramter will be in body.

Although Post is better for that reason you will still will be in Risk if you send this request over http not https.

Answer (score 0):

You should **always use POST** for sending passwords. The reason is that url shouldn't contain sensitive data like a password because it gets saved (for example the logs on your server contain url by default). You don't want password saved in plaintext anywhere.